# Use information from view page source in automated test

Tags: java, selenium, testing, tags, automated-tests

Im trying to get some information from my page source. I run my automated tests on every release but want to avoid updating the release number manually as im trying to integrate my tests in CI and was hoping i could pull the  tag from the page source.

All i know that works here is Drivers.getDriver.getPageSource but have no idea how to pull information.

The main issue im having is that the version is in 2 sections:

< meta http-equiv="version" content="1.4.39" >

I want to be able to take the 1.4.39 out of the page source and add to string

Comment: add to which _...string..._?

Comment: As far as I understood, you are trying to build the application first from CI and then pick the build number from the application using the source code of the application. But why do you want to do so?

Comment: For whatever you are trying to do, you can take the entire page source in a String and then take out the value and keep that in a different String

Comment: Basically when I run my tests they update to testrail through an api, so the version can be updated in testrail for audit purposes. Currently im just updating this manually through a String version = "version number", Im able to get the page source but no idea how to actually grab the information. The fact that im using Ci doesnt really matter at the moment, just getting the version number is good for me

Answer (score 5):

This surely is possible, you just had to have locator for this element.
For example if I take it's cssSelector as:

> meta[http-equiv*='version']

We can easily do this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("meta[http-equiv*='version']")).getAttribute("content")
```

This will return you 1.4.39 as String value.

Hope this helped.